# Hive queries on external S3 table very slow

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr, parquet

We have our dataset in s3 (parquet files) in the below format, data divided as multiple parquet files based on the row number

```
data1_1000000.parquet
data1000001_2000000.parquet
data2000001_3000000.parquet
...
```

Created hive table on top of it using,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_hive (
  foo string
) STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://myBucket/myParquet/';
```

Totally there 22000 parquet files and the size of the folder is nearly 300GB. When i run the count query on this table in Hive, it is taking 6 hours to return the result which is nearly 7 billion records. How can we make it faster? Can i create partition or index on the table or this is the time it usually take when pulling data from s3. Can anyone advice, what is wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: You're reading thousands of files from S3 and expecting it to be fast? The max key request is limited to 1000, I believe, and thats 22 requests of pages, then one round-trip HTTP request per file. Add in downloading each file on whatever connection speed is between HiveServer,  YARN,  and S3 and parsing file contents to run a row count.... Partitioning won't help a total row count, only for that partition

Comment: FWIW, if you're using EMR, use Presto or SparkSQL  to do this instead

Comment: Thanks for that, however total folder size is nearly 300GB, dont we need that big cluster size atleast to handle it in SparkSQL which needs to keep data in Memory?

Comment: 32 GB of memory across 10 worker nodes? That's not a big cluster, in my opinion. That amount of memory is also not large for what EC2 offers

Comment: Hmm. Let me try that then. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to change the cluster node type of an existing cluster ? I have chosen m3 instances initially.

Comment: I've not used EMR much but you might be able to add additional nodes. I doubt you can change instance type at runtime

Comment: Hey hi, did you suggest what sort performance can we improve still in s3?. because data will not be lost when it comes to s3 rather than hdfs